# Passing mapDispatchToProps as an object or a function to connect have the same outcome

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm beginner, learning React with Redux, I came across a situation where,

These two code samples lead to the same result:

case 1: without using **dispatch**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,
    {
        getContacts : () => {
            return {
                type:GET_CONTACTS
            }
        }
    }
    )(Contacts);
```

case 2: using **dispatch**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,
    dispatch => ({
        getContacts : () => {
            return dispatch({type:GET_CONTACTS})
        }
    })
    )(Contacts);
```

- Can someone explain me why does these two code examples work in the same way?
- And why we don't need to use **dispatch** in **case 1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would result the same. There are [two ways](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops) to define `mapDispatchToProps`.

- **Function form**: Allows more customization, gains access to `dispatch` and optionally `ownProps`.
- **Object shorthand form**: More declarative and easier to use.

#### Why to do `dispatch` instead of calling function normally?

> In `redux` the `store` is **single source of truth**, the `dispatch` you are using is actually comes from `store` (`store.dispatch`).

> If you call a function normally then it won't be aware by the `store`. That action won't pass through the `middlewares` (thunk/saga) that `store` is aware of and won't do perform `store` update via `reducers`.

> If `store` is not updated, your `connected components` won't receive any updates. **Eventually your UI won't re-render.**